# Really dynamic JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I need to create a "real" dynamic JPA `CriteriaBuilder`. I get an `Map<String, String>` with the statements. It looks like:

```
name : John
surname : Smith
email : email@email.de

...more pairs possible
```

Here is what i implement:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> userRoot = query.from(User.class);
query.select(userRoot);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Iterator<String> column = statements.keySet().iterator();
while (column.hasNext()) {

    // get the pairs
    String colIndex = column.next();
    String colValue = statements.get(colIndex);

    // create the statement
    Predicate pAnd = cb.conjunction();
    pAnd = cb.and(pAnd, cb.equal(userRoot.get(colIndex), colValue));
    predicates.add(pAnd);
}

// doesn't work, i don't know how many predicates i have -> can not address them
query.where(predicates.get(0), predicates.get(1), ...);

// doesn't work, because it is a list of predicates
query.where(predicates);

// doesn't work, because the actual predicate overwrites the old predicate
for (Predicate pre : predicates) {
     query.where(pre)
}
```

I tried to build a big `Predicate`, which contains all other predicates and add this to the `query.where()`, but again the predicates overwrites old values. Looks like there is no possibility to add a `Predicate` instead of change a Predicate :-(

The real project is even more complicated, because some pairs requires an `equal` and some other a `like`. And that is not even enough: There could a extra statement with `or` included like `type : 1;4;7`. Here the value have to split up and create a statement like:

`<rest of statement> AND (type = 1 OR type = 4 OR type = 7)`

**UPDATE and SOLUTION**
Got two lists, first List for AND works well. Second list contains OR statements like exspected:

```
final List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
final List<Predicate> orPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
for (final Entry<String, String> entry : statements.entrySet()) {
    final String colIndex = entry.getKey();
    final String colValue = entry.getValue();
    if (colIndex != null && colValue != null) {

        if (!colValue.contains(";")) {
            if (equals) {
                andPredicates.add(cb.equal(userRoot.get(colIndex), colValue));
            } else {
                andPredicates.add(cb.like(userRoot.<String> get(colIndex), "%" + colValue + "%"));
            }
        } else {
            String[] values = colValue.split(";");
            for (String value : values) {
                orPredicates.add(cb.or(cb.equal(userRoot.get(colIndex), value)));
            }
        }       
    }
}

// Here goes the magic to combine both lists
if (andPredicates.size() > 0 && orPredicates.size() == 0) {
    // no need to make new predicate, it is already a conjunction
    query.where(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[andPredicates.size()]));
} else if (andPredicates.size() == 0 && orPredicates.size() > 0) {
    // make a disjunction, this part is missing above
    Predicate p = cb.disjunction();
    p = cb.or(orPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[orPredicates.size()]));
    query.where(p);
} else {
    // both types of statements combined
    Predicate o = cb.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[andPredicates.size()]));
    Predicate p = cb.or(orPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[orPredicates.size()]));
    query.where(o, p);
}

query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
users = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can pass an array of predicates to the `CriteriaBuilder`, deciding on `equal` or `like` as you go. For this, build a list and pack the contents of the list into an array in a single `and` statement. Like this:

```
final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

for (final Entry<String, String> e : myPredicateMap.entrySet()) {

    final String key = e.getKey();
    final String value = e.getValue();

    if ((key != null) && (value != null)) {

        if (value.contains("%")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String> get(key), value));
        } else {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(key), value));
        }
    }
}

query.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
query.select(count);
```

In case you need to distingiush between `and` and `or`, use two lists.

Comment: Okay, for my AND statements that work. I create a second List and stored my OR statements in that list. At the end, I do what? Copy both list togehter results in AND for both types of statements.

My `orPredicates` list contains the correct elements. Even when I only add this list to the query, all statements put together with AND.

Comment: You can create a disjunction (or) the same way you create a conjunction (and) - by calling `or` and `and` methods on the CriteriaBuilder. The return is a single `Predicate` in both cases - so if you dont have some sort of complex grouping, simply call `and` on the two resulting Predicates and use the result in the `where`

Comment: Maybe I got it now, I updated the main question and post my solution.

Answer (score 22):

One option is to use the fact that method with variable number of arguments can take an array:

```
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

Alternatively, you can combine them into a single predicate (note that if you don't do it, you don't need to create a conjunction as in your example);:

```
Predicate where = cb.conjunction();
while (column.hasNext()) {
    ...
    where = cb.and(where, cb.equal(userRoot.get(colIndex), colValue));
}

query.where(where);
```

Answer (score 6):

I have always been thinking that creation of solution like that is like reinventing the bicycle.
Here https://github.com/sasa7812/jfbdemo is my solution. It was tested on EclipseLink and Hibernate
(EclipseLink in production, we used it in several projects for simple cases).
Sometimes you just need a quick solution to make a dataTable with sorting and filtering, nothing fancy. 
It is able to filter and sort on joined fields, and even on collections.
Project contains demo on Primefaces showing the abilities of FilterCriteriaBuilder.
In the heart of it you just need this:

```
 public List<T> loadFilterBuilder(int first, int pageSize, Map<String, Boolean> sorts, List<FieldFilter> argumentFilters, Class<? extends AbstractEntity> entityClass) {
    FilterCriteriaBuilder<T> fcb = new FilterCriteriaBuilder<>(getEntityManager(), (Class<T>) entityClass);
    fcb.addFilters(argumentFilters).addOrders(sorts);
    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(fcb.getQuery());
    q.setFirstResult(first);
    q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

to get the results from database.

I really need someone to tell me that it is usefull and is used somewhere to continue my work on this library.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to Predicate ... as follows

```
query.where( predicates.stream().toArray( Predicate[]::new ) );
```

Comment: or even shorter query.where( predicates.toArray( Predicate[]::new ) );

Answer (score 0):

For Predicate you can create new ArrayList add all your predicate to the list and then at the end you can create a predicate array and convert list to predicate array and directly assign it to criteriabuilder.where(new Pridicate[])