# Is there generic Specification for JPASpecificationExecutor to use in Web

Tags: jpa, orm, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data has a native web support for Pageable send over the web, as parameters in HTML Query, through PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

I have not found JPA Specification executor for that, which from my point of view would be very useful.

Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that there's no generic one available for you is that the predicates you build in it is completely depending on your domain model. A good example for how to use `Specification`s with Spring MVC can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280708/filtering-database-rows-with-spring-data-jpa-and-spring-mvc/20283256#20283256).