# What is a Generic Specification in Web Programming?

Tags: specifications

What is a 'generic specification' with regards to web programming, specifically for PHP or JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Thanks @d-everhard for your suggested edits. Still learning here.

Answer (score 1):

A software specification is a text describing the developing goals and features of a software project. This text is usually written during planning phase, before any code is being written for the project. It often contains information about the software and frameworks that is being used, the software architecture, database schemas and other design decisions.

A generic specification in particular is a software specification that does not go much in detail about the implementation, and is rather an early concept of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
That is what I initially assumed until I started to research it on both Google and Stack Overflow. I think (but not 100% sure) that it is something to do with Design Patterns and Domain Modelling. 
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722419/is-there-generic-specification-for-jpaspecificationexecutor-to-use-in-web 
Hence my question here :-)

Comment: My answer might be wrong then. Maybe you can put that link in your question to help future answerers. Also, this might help: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#specifications