# Search with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, search, spring-data-jpa

I have a UI with a `Grid<Item>` (with sorting, filtering, paging) to a Spring service backed by JPA. Must be a pretty common thing.

`Item` fields: `a`, `b`, `c` (there are a lot more fields in reality, but for the purpose of the example I'll keep it short)

If someone wants to filter for `a=valueA` and `c=valueC` items, I would like the URL for example to be something like this:

```
/items?a=valueA&c=valueC&orderBy=b&page=2&pageSize=50
```

I found [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283256/1419386), but I can not figure out how to facilitate the binding of the URL parameters to the `@ModelAttribute`. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this code for this type of url.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public RestResponse findAll(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int page, @RequestParam(value = "pagesize", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int pagesize, @RequestParam(value = "a", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") String a, @RequestParam(value = "c", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") String c, @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") String orderBy) {

.
.
.



  }
```