# Building query dynamically

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, java-11, jooq

I have a requirement where I need to build query dynamically i.e., which columns to select, from which tables and which joins to use.

Is there any existing library that I can use?

I have already looked into **Spring Projections** but it doesn't serve the purpose. It requires projection (interface) needed to be defined before hand.

I am also looking at `JOOQ`. It looks like it may serve the purpose but before I dig into this, I wanted to see if there is anything built into Spring or there are any other better option?

P.S: I need queries for Azure SQL Dialect

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687817/how-to-have-filtering-of-multiple-parameters-passed-as-requestparams-in-spring-d/69688578#69688578

Answer (score 0):

[jOOQ's dynamic SQL support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/) answers pretty much all of your questions. I'm not aware of anything by Spring itself that can model jOOQ's support for complex dynamic SQL