# Is there a way to pass a jpa predicate array to the criteriabuilder IN KOTLIN?

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin, syntax, hibernate-criteria

The solution proposed in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11138229/1270045
works pretty fine in java but i am in kotlin.
How can that be done here that i pass a predicate array to the criteria builder written in kotlin?

So its about writing this in kotlin that i can be passed on:

```
cq.select(customer).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

My example code:

```
val predicates = mutableListOf<Predicate>()
if (XYZ != null) {
    val XYZPath = element.get<Long>("XYZ")
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(XYZPath, XYZ))
}
criteriaQuery.select(element)
    .where(criteriaBuilder.or(???))
```

Comment: Is it the `predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])` part you have trouble with?

Comment: If so, then try `predicates.toTypedArray()`

Comment: Yes and i tried that but a java array is expected as the java method is defined by `Predicate ...` as parameter

Comment: Oh, it expects a vararg. Try `*predicates`.

Comment: That seems to work. Will confirm when it runs :)

Comment: That did it, thanks @marstran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to marstran for your help that solved it:

```
criteriaQuery.select(element)
    .where(criteriaBuilder.or(*predicates.toTypedArray()))
```