# Dynamic SELECT and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot

We have a requirement in our spring boot application where it is required to generate a query with dynamic SELECT clause and WHERE clause. User would choose specific columns during runtime and only those need to be fetched. How can this be achieved?
As far as I have searched about dynamic queries, I can understand the dynamic part can be done for WHERE clause. But, not sure how to do the SELECT clause dynamically.

Editing to add example:
Table has `columns id`, `name`, `role`, `salary`.

Query:

```
select id, name from Table Where role = 'Admin';
```

Here, `WHERE clause (role = Admin)` and the columns to be `selected(id, name)` will be known only at runtime.

Comment: Can you afford an example input/output?

Comment: Edited to add example.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a query builder - is https://querybuilder.js.org/ what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(getDomainClass());
final Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(getDomainClass());

criteriaQuery.select(root);
ParameterExpression<Integer> p = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Integer.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.gt(root.get("<whatever>"), p));

final TypedQuery<T> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getResultList();
```

If that does not fit your idea, have a look at this post [Really dynamic JPA CriteriaBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138118/really-dynamic-jpa-criteriabuilder)